# Bloquear usuario en auth firebase y no dejarlo ingresar a la APP

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas, tengo un login hecho en Android para ingresar con Gmail guardando la autentificacion en firebase, la app ingresa ok y crea la autentificacion en fire generando el User UID correspondiente. Ahora veo que en las opciones de cada usuario tengo los items reset password, disabled account y delete account. Al tildar disabled no pasa nada, como puedo hacer para validar si la cuenta esta enabled o disabled y en caso de disabled no dejar ingresar al login por error en las credenciales?

Comment: deberías revisar bien tu codigo, al inhabilitar ya que con inhabilitar cuenta no te debe permitir loguearte a través de firebase

Comment: Cuando deshabilias un usuario desde la consola, no se le aplica el cambio al momento en la pagina que este consultando, necesita recargar o mandar una peticion para que le muestre que esta bloqueado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La validación se hace solicitando el token del usuario actual, si el usuario está dado de baja, firebase nos retorna una respuesta fallida con un string que contiene la cadena "USER_DISABLE"...
Perdón si mi código está en Java 8:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        user.getToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                        openHome();
                    }
                })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("USER_DISABLED")){
                String message = getString(R.string.user_disabled);
                logOut(message);
            }
        });

    }
```